# Replicating the scrolling behavior of the Wallet app in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am attempting to replicate the scrolling behavior of the Wallet app in SwiftUI. Specifically, I want to achieve the effect where scrolling up all the way on a card view returns to the main view.

[image: Wallet App Effect]

To accomplish this, I have implemented the following code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isCardVisible = true
    @State private var dragOffset: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.gray.ignoresSafeArea()
            
            if isCardVisible {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack(spacing: 20) {
                        Text("Card View")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                            .offset(y: max(dragOffset, 0))
                            .gesture(
                                DragGesture()
                                    .onChanged { value in
                                        dragOffset = value.translation.height
                                    }
                                    .onEnded { value in
                                        if dragOffset < -200 {
                                            isCardVisible = false
                                        } else {
                                            dragOffset = 0
                                        }
                                    }
                            )
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
                .overlay(
                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        Color.clear
                            .preference(key: OffsetPreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.frame(in: .global).origin.y)
                    }
                )
                .onPreferenceChange(OffsetPreferenceKey.self) { offset in
                    if offset < -200 {
                        isCardVisible = false
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if !isCardVisible {
                Button("Show Card") {
                    isCardVisible = true
                }
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(8)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct OffsetPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = 0
    
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
```

In my implementation, I use a `ZStack` to layer the views. The card view is displayed within a `ScrollView` and can be scrolled up or down. The `dragOffset` state variable is used to track the vertical translation of the card view when dragged.

To handle the exit behavior, I employ a `DragGesture` on the card view. When the user scrolls up and releases their finger, the `onEnded` closure checks if the `dragOffset` is less than `-200`. If it is, the `isCardVisible` state is set to `false`, and the card view is hidden.

Additionally, I include an overlay using a `GeometryReader` to detect the scroll offset of the card view. The `OffsetPreferenceKey` is used to store and track the offset value, and the `onPreferenceChange` modifier is utilized to check if the offset is less than `-200`, triggering the exit behavior.

Despite my efforts, the scrolling behavior does not match the desired effect seen in the Wallet app. I have attached the code I've implemented along with this question.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to modify this code to accurately replicate the scrolling behavior of the Wallet app, where scrolling up all the way returns to the main view? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question and code shows you did a lot of research on this. Unfortunately, you tried to combine everything you found into this one view. The first problem you were having is you can't have a vertical `ScrollView` and a vertical `DragGesture` together. It doesn't work. Second, `DragGestures` and `PreferenceKeys` don't really work together like that. In this instance, you don't even need the `DragGesture`, just the `PreferenceKey`. Third, don't place an offset on a view in a `ScrollView` that changes the vertical location of the view. If the `DragGesture` were to  have worked occasionally, your view would be jumping up and down. Just let the `ScrollView` handle that. Commented code below:

```
struct ScrollDownToHide: View {
    @State private var isCardVisible = true
    @State private var dragOffset: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.gray.ignoresSafeArea()
            
            if isCardVisible {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack(spacing: 20) {
                        Text("Card View")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                            // The GeometryReader needs to be on the card view itself.
                            // You need to know where card view is, not the
                            // ScrollView's location on the screen.
                            .overlay(
                                GeometryReader { geometry in
                                    Color.clear
                                        .preference(key: OffsetPreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.frame(in: .global).origin.y)
                                }
                            )
                            // This could have been anywhere in the view as long as it
                            // was on a visible view.
                            .onPreferenceChange(OffsetPreferenceKey.self) { value in
                                dragOffset = value
                            }
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
                // read the dragOffset in an `.onChange(of:)` to catch the updated values.
                // SwiftUI's origin in this case has (0,0) in the upper left
                // so origin.y will increase as the card goes down the screen.
                .onChange(of: dragOffset) { newValue in
                    if newValue > 200 {
                        withAnimation {
                            isCardVisible.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Button("Show Card") {
                    isCardVisible = true
                }
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(8)
            }
        }
    }
}

// With the PreferenceKey, you do not need the func reduce to do anything to the value,
// you are simply passing the y value along.
struct OffsetPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = 0
    
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {}
}
```

[image]

Lastly, the actual animation of placing the card back into its place is called a "Hero Animation", and it uses a `MatchedGeometry` effect. Google that and you will find plenty of tutorials regarding using it.